# Wanting to toggle class, when value is greater than 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use "toggleClass" when the numeric value inside of the span.points is greater than "0". So it'll null, and then, if the value changes to 1, it'll add a class. Not sure how to accomplish this? Learning jQuery at snails pace... any help would be helpful. Thank you guys!

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <span class="points">4</span>
</div>
```

**Failed JS Attempt**

```
var points = $('.box > .points').length;
if(points > 0) {
    $('.box').toggleClass('orange');
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You HTML doesn't match your jQuery selectors. You don't have an element with the class `count-box` or `cart-count`. `.length` is used for the amount of elements, not to check what number is in the element.

Comment: First of all, there is no `count-box`, `cart-count`, or even `has-dropdown`. I am guessing you are copying codes from elsewhere and you want us to fix it so it suits your case?

Comment: This will get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/r7ty8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `.text()` or `.html()` and parse that to a number.

```
var points = parseFloat($('.box > .points').text());
if(points > 0) {
    $('.box').toggleClass('orange');
} else {
    return false;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4m49N/1/)

Don't forget to either put that in a function or in an `$(document).ready({ ... })` statement.